# string poniter in c is not working when writen with *

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I had written this c program for study purpose and I have found that

`printf("%s",a);` works but `printf("%s",*a);` does not works.

I had defined `a` like this `char *a[]="how are you";`

why `*a`is not pointing towards the string?

I am getting this error

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:7:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%s \n",*a);
         ~^     ~~
        %d
```

Comment: `char *a[]="how are you";` should be `char *a[]={"how are you"};`

Comment: You should always, ***always*** compile with `-Wall` (or equivalent for your compiler) and heed those warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **undefined behaviour** because of  `%s` printf interprets `*a` as an address, but it's actually not an address and if you treat it as address it points to some location that is read protected for your program. So,may be you get segmentation fault.

Comment: yes. i am getting segmentation fault.but in the case of other pointers ,like int,i had to write *a to print the value stored at the adders of a.